# Syncing People 8.1 to PC

Tags: 8.1, windows-10

Stupid question but how on earth do you get 'people' (contacts) on a windows 8.1 phone to appear on a windows 10 pc? Both are logged in with the same account of course. Basically I only have one person showing up on my PC but have hundreds on my phone. I cannot for the life of me see the difference between this one person and all the others.

Comment: Do you sign in to the same providers with the same accounts on both devices?

Comment: Do these contacts show up in https://people.live.com ?